# How do I get zone offset for a location?

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

I have an API written in Spring. For the date and time properties, I use the Java Time API (more specifically `LocalDateTime`) and an Android client which is heavily reliant on time related information.

When the client issues a request, it can send the city where the user is located.

How can I obtain a `ZoneOffset` from the information in the request so the date and time in the response are appropriate to the user's location?

Comment: So you have the city as a String and you want to obtain the zone offset from that? Do you have the country also? I don't know if it exists in reality but it might be theoretically possible to have, in the same country, two cities having the same name and being in two different time zones (take the US for example). I think you would be better off asking the user its timezone.

Comment: what is "information in the request"? REST request or something?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the capital of the state you are in, you can use it's TimeZone as these are available.  The trick is knowing which state or province you are in.

If you know the lat/lot you can work out the likely difference from GMT and whether you are in day light saving but this would be approximate.